# Contructing a $\delta$-fine tagged partition from the old ones

Tags: real-analysis, integration, partitions-for-integration

Let $[a,b]\subset \mathbb{R}$. A *tagged partition* of $[a,b]$ is a set
$D=\{(t_i,I_i)\}_{i=1}^m$ where $\{I_i\}_{i=1}^m$ is a *partition* of $[a,b]$ consisting of closed non-overlapping subintervals of $[a,b]$ and $t_i\in I_i$; $t_i$ is called the *tag* associated with $I_i$.

Suppose that $D=\{(t_i,I_i)\}_{i=1}^m$ and $D'=\{(s_j,J_j)\}_{i=1}^n$
are any two tagged partitions of $[a,b]$. We say that $D'$ is *finer* than $D$ if for each  $j\in\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$, there exists $i\in\{1,2,\cdots,m\}$ such that $J_j\subset I_i$ and every tag in $D$ is a tag in $D'$.

Let $\delta:[a,b]\to (0,+\infty)$ be a positive function. We say that a tagged partition $D=\{(t_i,I_i)\}_{i=1}^m$ is $\delta$-fine if
$$I_i\subset(t_i-\delta(t_i),t_i+\delta(t_i))\quad\mbox{for } i=1,2,\cdots,m.$$

**Question:**

Suppose $D$ and $D'$ are $\delta$-fine tagged partitions of $[a,b]$. How do we construct a third $\delta$-fine tagged partition $E$ of $[a,b]$ such that $E$ is both finer than $D$ and $D'$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things to keep track of:

- The partitions;
- The tags.

On an intuitive level, they can be taken care of by the family $(I_i \cap J_j)_{i,j}$, placing the old tags as appropriate, and making up some new ones for those intervals not containing an old tag (this may require further splitting of the intervals, depending on $\delta$). We also need to split those $I_i \cap J_j$ that contain both $t_i$ and $s_j$ (presuming they are distinct, of course).

---

A more detailed version of the sketch above:

Denote $K_{ij} = I_i \cap J_j$; then $(K_{ij})_{ij}$ is a partition of $[a,b]$ of the required form.

Note that if we produce a tagged partition $E_{ij}$ for each $K_{ij}$, we can amalgamate these into a tagged partition $E$ of $[a,b]$. So fix a $K_{ij}$, and distinguish four cases:

- $t_i, s_j \in K_{ij}$: if $t_i = s_j$, use the tagged partition $\{(K_{ij},t_i)\}$. Otherwise, use the partition $\{(K_{ij}\cap[a,r],t_i \wedge s_j),(K_{ij}\cap[r,b],t_i \vee s_j)\}$, where $r = \frac12(t_i+s_j)$, and $\wedge$ and $\vee$ denote the binary $\max$ and $\min$ operations, respectively.
- $t_i \in K_{ij}$, $s_j \notin K_{ij}$: use the tagged partition $\{(K_{ij}, t_i)\}$.
- $t_i \notin K_{ij}$, $s_j \in K_{ij}$: use the tagged partition $\{(K_{ij}, s_j)\}$.
- $t_i, s_j \notin K_{ij}$: For each $r \in K_{ij}$, let $L_r = (r-\frac12\delta(r),r+\frac12\delta(r)) \cap K_{ij}$. Then each $L_r$ is open in the subspace topology, and $\bigcup\limits_{r \in K_{ij}} L_r = K_{ij}$. Since $K_{ij}$ is compact, find a finite subset $r_k, 1\le k \le \ell$ such that $\bigcup_k L_{r_k} = K_{ij}$ and $k<k'$ implies $r_k < r_{k'}$. Denote with $\bar L_r$ the closed interval corresponding to $L_r$. Use the tagged partition $$\{(\bar L_{r_k}, r_k):1\le k\le\ell\}$$ where $L_{r_0} = \varnothing$ (we will let rest the boring details for dealing with the non-trivial overlapping of $L_{r_k}$).

This construction yields a tagged partition $E_{ij}$ of each $K_{ij}$, and hence of $[a,b]$; call this latter tagged partition $E$. It is to be verified that $E$ refines $D$ and $D'$.

Now each $K_{ij}$ is contained in both $I_i$ and $J_j$, and hence all intervals used for $E_{ij}$ are, too; furthermore, each tag $t_i, s_j$ occurs in *some* $K_{ij}$, and by construction remains a tag in $E$. Thus $E$ refines $D$ and $D'$.

Finally, it remains to establish that $E$ is $\delta$-fine. We restrict attention to the tags within one $E_{ij}$. If this $E_{ij}$ was formed using one of the first three constructions, it is immediate from the $\delta$-fineness of $D$ and $D'$ that $E_{ij}$ is $\delta$-fine. For the fourth construction, observe that $L_{r_k}$ is *strictly* contained in $(r_k-\delta(r_k),r_k+\delta(r_k))$, since $\delta(r_k)>0$; therefore, $\bar L_{r_k}$ is also contained in this set, and hence so are the intervals used in the partition. In conclusion, all $E_{ij}$, and consequently $E$, are $\delta$-fine.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Im still trying to picture out your suggestion.

Comment: How do we split those $I_i\cap J_j$ that contain both $t_i$ and $s_j$?

Comment: Simply replace $I_i \cap J_j$ by two intervals with union $I_i \cap J_j$ and intersection $r$, such that $r$ is between $t_i$ and $s_j$.

Comment: Ahh okay, Im still trying to look for other possibilities. Thanks for your last comment. I got what you mean

Comment: I got a problem on choosing a new tag in case $I_i\cap J_j$ does not contain both $t_i$ and $s_j$. How can we dot it?

Comment: It's the most intricate part; I suspected you'd ask a question about this. The trick is that our interval (denote it $[a,b]$) is closed, hence compact. We have the open cover $\{(r-\delta(r)/2,r+\delta(r)/2)\mid r \in [a,b]\}$. By compactness, find a finite subcover, i.e. $r_1,\ldots r_k$ such that $[a,b] \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^k (r_i-\delta(r_i)/2,r_i+\delta(r_i)/2)$. We can then take the corresponding closed intervals as a refinement (cutting the intervals off at the end-points by intersecting with $[a,b]$) and the $r_i$ as tags; by construction, it will remain $\delta$-fine.

Comment: Im still thinking in deep..:)Sorry Im  not that smart as you are..

Comment: I'm a bit short on time right now, but I'll try to add a more verbose, complete and rigorous version of the argument to the answer later tonight. It is likely more to do with a difference in experience than with smartness that you're struggling a bit. But keep in mind: When you understand it, you'll (hopefully) have learned some nice things and gained some experience!

Comment: Does it mean that in case $I_i\cap J_j$ does not contain both $t_i$ and $s_j$, then I have to pick some $r_s$, $1\le s\le k$, as the tag of $I_i\cap J_j$?

Comment: I would be greatful to you if you can add some thoughts of your answer! Thanks in advance

Comment: Added; there is a minute gap in rigour in the most intricate case, but it's (hopefully) clear that this does not pose serious problems.

Comment: wow thank you very much. You did a lot on solving the problem. More power to you Sir!